# Detect Usage of Variables in Angular 2 Template Literal

Tags: angular, sublimetext3, sublimetext, eslint, tslint

I am using Sublime Text 3 and ESLint.

When I define my Angular 2 template using the template literal syntax, by some reason ESLint doesn't catch the methods and properties usage.

Example:

```
@Component({
    ..., // omitted for brevity
    template: `
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="toggleOpenAssessment()">
            {{ isOpen ? 'close' : 'open' }} assessment
        </button>
    `
})
export class MyComponentComponent {
    private isOpen: boolean = false;

    private toggleOpenAssessment() { return true; }
}
```

The errors I am getting from ESLint:

- Unused method: 'toggleOpenAssessment'
- Unused property: 'isOpen'

Does anybody know how I can adjust ESLint to detect the methods and properties I use in the template literals too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sadly, I found that currently a solution to this problem doesn't exist.**

The property connected to this behavior is the TSLint's `no-unused-variable`.

Checking the Angular 2 template file (or template literal) for references is out-of-scope for TSLint because they rely on TypeScript's Language Service APIs for finding occurrences of values.

I finally [found a related GitHub issue](http://Checking%20a%20template%20file%20for%20references%20feels%20out-of-scope%20for%20TSLint%20because%20we%20rely%20on%20TypeScript's%20Language%20Service%20APIs%20for%20finding%20occurrences%20of%20values.%20I%20don't%20think%20TSLint%20will%20do%20this%20unless%20the%20LS%20does%20static%20analysis%20of%20templates%20(there%20is%20some%20hope%20for%20this;%20see%20Microsoft/TypeScript#3003%20and%20Microsoft/TypeScript#5151).) with an [answer from Adi Dahiya](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1295#issuecomment-224585675). He says:

> Having tslint look into Angular templates is complex. To do it right, we really need to use Angular's template expression parser to get 100% compatibility, then hook Angular as an extension in TypeScript language service. We are close to a first version of VSCode support for angular templates. I'd like to figure out the linting story soon after.

That leaves us with just a few ugly workarounds:

- do not use `private` properties at all
- switch off the `no-unused-variable` flag in the TSLint configuration

I hope that in near future they find a way to do this really awesome feature!

PS: Additionally, there's [a proposal for no-unused-variable deprecation](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1481).

Comment: I found a similar problem with `template-use-public`. codelyzer's latest version doesn't seem to notice private members being used in templates.